# When is Ubuntu likely to have systemd 251?

Tags: systemd, 22.04

I'm just curious how the community handicaps when Ubuntu will implement systemd 251.  Currently, 22.04 implements systemd 249.

- Is it likely to be in an upcoming release, *e.g.*, 22.04.1 or 22.04.2?
- Is it likely to be delayed until another version, *e.g.*, 22.10?
- Is it likely to be delayed until another LTS, *e.g.*, 24.04?

Comment: @absf https://launchpad.net/systemd/+packages 22.10 is planned to have 2.51 And 22.04.2 = 22.10 ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind, thanks for the information.  Thanks also for responding squarely and concisely to the question posed, which seems to escape many.

Comment: What does "handicapping" mean here? It doesn't fit the common meanings in, e.g. [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/handicap)

Comment: @Rinzwind it might show up in 22.10, but I don't think upgrading systemd to another major version will ever happen in an LTS release

Comment: @muru but at that time it will be pretty easy to do if someone wanted to.

Comment: @muru https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping

Comment: @Sneftel The sporting definition is included on the page that muru already linked to, but I don't understand its relevance here. The question seems to just be asking "how the community *chooses* when..." Perhaps the intent was something like "what are the restrictions on that choice", but that's more of a "rule" than a "handicap".

Comment: @IMSoP "Handicapping" in this case means "estimating the chances of an outcome". As you can see from the OP's use of "likely", they were unaware that plans had already been made and were likely to be followed, so they were looking for educated guesses.

Comment: @Sneftel OK, that is indeed a meaning I hadn't heard before, and sort of makes sense in context. For future reference, this is why pasting a link with no context isn't always that useful, because I completely overlooked that section of the Wikipedia page so was none the wiser.

Comment: @IMSoP I'll be honest, I'd just scanned the WP page, and I was unaware of the meaning used in the *first* paragraph. LANGUAGE WOOOO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/systemd/+packages) holds a list of all packages and their version number. That includes the Ubuntu yet to be released.

In the case of systemd the list is ...

```
Distribution    Package     Version      
Kinetic (22.10) systemd     251.2-2ubuntu1  
Jammy (22.04)   systemd     249.11-0ubuntu3.4   
Impish (21.10)  systemd     248.3-1ubuntu8.6    
Hirsute (21.04) systemd     247.3-3ubuntu3.7    
Focal (20.04)   systemd     245.4-4ubuntu3.17   
Bionic (18.04)  systemd     237-3ubuntu10.53    
Xenial (16.04)  systemd     229-4ubuntu21.31    
Trusty (14.04)  systemd     204-5ubuntu20.31
```

So the 1st Ubuntu intended to have 251 is 22.10.

Ubuntu will not update older releases unless there are security issues (and then only that issue is patched)  so 22.04 will not see 251. The point releases are hardware stacks and systemd is not part of that.

As soon as 22.10 arrives 22.04 could be updated to use systemd 251 but it would defeat using an LTS (you basically could upgrade 22.04 to 22.10).